# Postfix maintenance

Tags: postfix

Are there any tips for postfix server maintenance?

I noticed that it sticks sometimes or runs very slow.

I was thinking there might be a daemonized script running in the background cleaning postfix mail queue?

Others tips are welcome as well.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the question is here.  Do you want to automate sifting through your mailqueue, or do you want to do something to speed up postfix?  Also, some details about what is running slow etc may help.  You can have postfix working with many things, like a SQL backend, spamassassin, various AV scrubbers... what is running slow?

Answer (score 4):

Postfix is one of the most lightweight and powerful pieces of software I have had pleasure to administer. You need to elaborate quite a bit more to get an answer here.

Does your server slow down to crawl? Are all the mails delivered slowly or only some? Are you only sending mail or also receiving? What kind of mail volume are we talking about? For me receiving 20 000+ emails per minute during botnet spam attacks goes without a hitch with Postfix and the server is mostly idle.